# How to create function postgresql join table in Hasura

Tags: postgresql, postgis, hasura

I want to create a function to calculate the distance and sort between user and geolayer. I do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_geolayer_near_user(location text) 
RETURNS TABLE(id int, layer_name text, gps_to_center_layer numeric, gps_belong_province boolean) AS $func$
    SELECT gl.id, gl.layer_name, ST_Distance(
            ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(gl.minx, gl.miny, gl.maxx, gl.maxy, 4326))))),
            location
        ) AS gps_to_center_layer,
        ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, 4326))))),
    ST_contains(
    ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, 4326))),
    ST_GeometryFromText(location)) 
     AS gps_belong_province
    --   
    FROM "GeoLayers" gl JOIN "Regions" r ON gl.province_id = r.id
    WHERE gl.deleted_flg = false 
    GROUP BY gl.id , gl.layer_name, r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, gl.minx, gl.miny, gl.maxx, gl.maxy
    ORDER BY gps_belong_province DESC, gps_to_center_layer ASC 
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

But error

> "SQL Execution Failed postgres-error : return type mismatch in
> function declared to return record"

The normal query would look like this:

```
select gl.id , gl.layer_name, ST_Distance(
        ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(gl.minx, gl.miny, gl.maxx, gl.maxy, 4326))))),
        'POINT(109.189083 12.272397)'
    ) as "GPS to center Layer",
    ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, 4326))))),
ST_contains(
ST_GeometryFromText(ST_AsText(ST_MakeEnvelope(r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, 4326))),
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(109.189083 12.272397)')) 
 as "GPS belong Province"
--   
from "GeoLayers" gl join "Regions" r ON gl.province_id = r.id
where gl.deleted_flg = false 
group by gl.id , gl.layer_name, r.minx, r.miny, r.maxx, r.maxy, gl.minx, gl.miny, gl.maxx, gl.maxy
-- having st_contains = false 
order by "GPS belong Province" desc, "GPS to center Layer" asc 
-- limit 10
;
```

Data return:

```
 id    layer_name   GPS to center Layer st_astext   GPS belong Province
"539"  Bản đồ địa chính VIP - Phường Vĩnh Phước, Thành phố Nha Trang, Tỉnh Khánh Hòa"   "0.009276001515402381"  "POINT(112.2530484505 10.3798475845001)"    "t"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is saying that declared columns and query result do not match. The important thing here is that 1) the declared table in the `RETURNS TABLE` contains exactly the same columns, 2) they are in the same order and 3) their data types match. See this examples:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(text,text) 
RETURNS TABLE(r1 text, r2 text) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT $1,$2;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('foo','bar');

 r1  | r2  
-----+-----
 foo | bar
```

.. or using SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(text,text) 
RETURNS TABLE(r1 text, r2 text) AS $$
SELECT $1,$2;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('foo','bar');

 r1  | r2  
-----+-----
 foo | bar
```

In your function the declared columns and query do not match. After a quick mapping I get:

- id *int*: `539`
- layer_name *text*: `Bản đồ địa chính VIP - Phường Vĩnh Phước, Thành phố -Nha Trang, Tỉnh Khánh Hòa`
- gps_to_center_layer *numeric*: `0.009276001515402381`
- gps_belong_province *boolean*: `POINT(112.2530484505 10.3798475845001)` (this is no boolean)
- In the end of your `SELECT` there is also a boolean `t` that was not declared.